# How to get the length of list elements if the list contains Widget types? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, list, dart, widget

I cannot get the length of all the elements in my list because it contains Widgets. Is there a way I can get around this? I use[image: following code]

to generate the list with the element lengths.

I'm getting the following error: `The element type 'List<Container>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable`.

This is an example of the contents list I'm trying to get the length from:
[image: Contents list]

I've tried list builder instead of list generator but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add spread operator at the front if the `List`, and use the `length` on the `List` normally.

```
children: [
...List.generate(contents.length, (index) => buildDot(index, context)), // add ... like this in your List
],
```

this will lead that your list will be merged with the principal list.

Comment: Thx for that! It works. Learning every day.